# Program containing only a single printf crashes

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("ass");
    return 0;

}
```

A code is written without errors, the program is compiled without problems, but at her opening she takes off without errors, id est simply closed
It is necessary for me that exe was started

Comment: which os , and are you doing it in terminal ?

Comment: ***simply closed*** That is the correct behavior. Most OSs will close an application after it finishes.

Comment: How are you running the program?  Is it from command line or are you running from and IDE or double clicking on a file manager?

Comment: windows 10 / visual studio 2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing console window from closing on Visual Studio C/C++ Console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio)

Comment: just include a scanf function below printf .. it will let you see the output .

Comment: You seem to be confusing a crash with a program which just starts and finishes quickly without any user input.

Comment: It is necessary for me that exe was started

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36799058/3313064

Answer (score 0):

> code written without errors (...)

No, not exactly. You can omit return value of `printf` function but actually it's [header](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) is a little different. Not to mention that some people would scold usage of C functions when C++ tag is given (use streams).

Why shouldn't You use `printf` without format string?

http://www.cprogramming.com/tips/tip/do-not-use-printf-without-percent-s-to-print-a-string

@Christian Hackl noticed in comment that it's quite safe to pass that particular string literal to `printf`, but consider what happens with one that has percent character [`%`], used inside `printf` https://stackoverflow.com/a/31293816/4476122

Now, program closes, and if You didn't see any output - word You so cleverly selected to share publicly with us - You might want to read about [buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991116/why-is-stdout-buffering).

Comment: Are you saying that the OP should check the return value of `printf` for errors? That seems like a lot of overkill.

Comment: No, I wrote that OP can omit (ignore) it. But `printf ("string")` is wrong, `printf ("%s\n", "string")` is ok

Comment: That's a half-truth, I'm afraid. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290850/why-is-printf-with-a-single-argument-without-conversion-specifiers-deprecated for the whole story. Of course, as you are correctly saying, the OP should use `std::cout` anyway.

Comment: True, string literals will usually get placed in RO memory and in this simple example as there are no other stack arguments, except for stdin environment variables, but still... maybe I was just being picky about "code written without errors". Although You made me think do `main(void)` gets env, and argv[0] at all...thanks :)